# Expected amount of items with weight probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose, you have a box $B$ with $n$ items and you pull $k<n$ items out of it. Items have different sizes $s_i$, with larger items being more probable to get pulled out:
$$p(i) = \frac{s_i}{\sum_{\forall j\in B}{s_j}}$$
What's the expected chance an item $i$ will be among the $k$ items you will have pulled out of the box? Is there some way to do it more easily than by bruteforcing the tree of probabilities?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545297/sampling-a-sequence-without-replacement-with-non-uniform-probability-of-sampling/4545318#4545318) is very similar (it asks for the probabilty that item $i$ is exactly the $k^\text{th}$ item pulled, not just among the first $k$). No full answer there, either, sadly.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163120/755